# How do I add custom user model fields to the Wagtail user settings page?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am building a wagtail site. I've followed [the instructions found in the docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html) and my additional fields show up in the edit and create user forms, found at [site url]/admin/users/[user id]. However, I want them to also show up in the account settings page accessed from the bottom left. [This page](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/custom_account_settings.html) seems to describe what I want to do, but I don't understand the instructions it gives.

I have an app named user, and my settings point the AUTH_USER_MODEL to the model User within it. My models.py in this app is as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bio = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=2048)
    nickname = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation of this user"""
        return self.get_full_name()
```

and my forms.py is

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from wagtail.users.forms import UserEditForm, UserCreationForm

class CustomUserEditForm(UserEditForm):
    nickname = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_("Nickname"))
    bio = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_("Bio"))


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    nickname = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_("Nickname"))
    bio = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_("Bio"))
```

From the docs it sounds like I would want to add something like this to that same forms.py:

```
class CustomSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nickname = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_("Nickname"))
    bio = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_("Bio"))
    
    class Meta:
        model = django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()
        fields = [...]
```

and this to the (otherwise empty) hooks.py:

```
from wagtail.admin.views.account import BaseSettingsPanel
from wagtail import hooks
from .forms import CustomSettingsForm

@hooks.register('register_account_settings_panel')
class CustomSettingsPanel(BaseSettingsPanel):
    name = 'custom'
    title = "My custom settings"
    order = 500
    form_class = CustomSettingsForm
    form_object = 'user'
```

I've tried a lot of variations on this, and I can't get anything to work. Usually I get no new fields in the accounts settings panel, and this error on the edit page:

```
TypeError at /admin/users/1/ sequence item 0: expected str instance, ellipsis found
```

All I want to do is allow the user to modify these additional fields from the user settings panel, as not all users will have permissions to edit the user model (as found at /admin/users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [@cnk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52325/cnk), the fields array should contain ['bio', 'nickname']. However, the main problem was a pretty silly one. In the docs it says to place the code containing `@hooks.register('register_account_settings_panel')` in `hooks.py`. I didn't notice that literally every other hooks file is named `wagtail_hooks.py`. Changing the file name to `wagtail_hooks.py` made things work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

"expected str instance, ellipsis found" sounds like you literally have `fields = [...]` in your code. The example in the docs expects you to put actual field names in that list. So perhaps `fields = ['bio', 'nickname']`?

Comment: It was one of the things I tried, gets rid of the error message but doesn't make the fields show up in the account settings tab. I had guessed maybe the elipses were a syntax I wasn't aware of. It looks like I'm just missing something that makes the hook actually activate. I wish there was a more comprehensive guide for this