# How to customize the Wagtail Admin Settings->Users list view (/admin/users/)?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

We would like to modify the visible columns on the Wagtail Admin Settings->Users list view, such as displaying an additional property on a custom User model. How can we modify the Wagtail Admin Settings->Users list view to add custom properties? I couldn't find any mention in the Wagtail docs aside from [customizing the user account settings form](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/custom_account_settings.html).

I searched the Wagtail documentation for any mention of customizing the Users listing page and hoped to find some information.

Comment: I also found the following issue that focuses on customizing the User forms, etc., but not the listing page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74132248/how-do-i-add-custom-user-model-fields-to-the-wagtail-user-settings-page?rq=2

Comment: I opened a feature request related to this question: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/11255

Answer (score 2):

To add fields to the user index view you will need to override the template - https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/generic_views.html#templates

If the data is already available in the page context, for example an extra field on the User model, you should be able to do what you want by copying the index template to the location discussed in the link above and then adding your column.